# Object with dynamic array, error when assigning value (write access violation.)

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

Full error message:

Exception thrown: write access violation.

this->data was 0x1110116.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

class SimpleSet {
public:
    /** Construct empty set **/
    SimpleSet() 
    {
        data = new int[8];
        currentSize = 0;
        maxSize = 8;
    }
    /** Destructor */
    ~SimpleSet()
    {
        delete[] data;
        data = nullptr;
    }
    /** Insert i into set, return true if the element was inserted, else false **/
    bool insert(int i)
    {
        if (find(i) == -1)
        {
            ++currentSize;
            if (currentSize == maxSize)
            {
                try // Return 0 if array can't be increased.
                {
                    int* temp = new int[maxSize += maxSize];

                    for (int j = 0; j < currentSize; ++j)
                    {
                        temp[j] = data[j];
                    }
                    temp[currentSize] = i;
                    delete[] data;
                    data = temp;
                    return 1;
                }
                catch(std::bad_alloc& ba)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {

                data[currentSize] = i; // THIS IS LINE 51!
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    /** Returns true if i is in the set **/
    bool exists(int i)
    {
        return ((find(i) == -1) ? 0 : 1);
    }
    /** Removes i from the set, return true if an element was removed **/
    bool remove(int i)
    {
        if (find(i) != -1)
        {
            for (int j = find(i); j < currentSize - 1; ++j)
            {
                data[j] = data[j + 1];
                data[currentSize--] = NULL;
            }

            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

private:
    /** Dynamic array containing set elements **/
    int *data;
    /** Current number of elements **/
    int currentSize;
    /** Max capasity of data **/
    int maxSize;

    /** Returns the index where i may be found, else an invalid index. **/
    int find(int i)
    {
        int index = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < currentSize; ++j)
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                std::cout << "Found element in set\n";
                return j;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

};
```

When I try to add elements to the SimpleSet i get the error. At line 51.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: The main file.

```
int main()
{
    SimpleSet testSet;

    testSet.insert(0);

    std::cout << testSet.exists(0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Restarted visual studios, now it works.. Sorry for the trouble..

Comment: Why not simply use `std::vector`?  Also, where is "line 51"?  And where is your `main` function?

Comment: It's an exercise.

Comment: An exercise that doesn't properly explain, copy constructors, assignment operators, the "rule of 3 and 5" (which you're missing all of them), is no exercise.  It is just a way to get someone learning C++ frustrated.

Comment: Rule of 5/3/0...

Comment: That's all on me. We've been through it, it's just a lot to take in on a semster..

Comment: @Viktor That `main` program [does not produce the error](http://ideone.com/LVsCxp).  But I do know one program that can produce errors, and it is 2 lines:  `{ SimpleTest testSet; SimpleTest testSet2 = testSet; }`

Comment: Side note, when you resize the array, the line `int* temp = new int[maxSize += maxSize]` adjusts the max size but you do not revert the value when you catch `std::bad_alloc`, which means that if allocating the new array fails, your object is left in an invalid state. That's probably not the error you are seeing, but I thought I would point it out anyway. It would be better to allocate `new int[maxSize * 2]` and then adjust `maxSize` after the allocation succeeds. (Same with `currentSize` by the way... you increment it before you know the operation will be successful.)

Comment: Thanks, good points, I'll get to fixing the catch.

Comment: Another thing, since you increment `currentSize` *before* setting the element, you are putting the first element at `data[1]` and not `data[0]`. So in `find()`, the first element you access will be uninitialized and of some unspecified value.